# How can I fix jumpy Android rendering performance due to GPU throttling? I don't need a high framerate, just a consistent one

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a GL live wallpaper that uses very little CPU and only modest GPU. On my older test phone, it can run at a full 58fps  or so most of the time. But occasionally the effects ramp up, and then the render times jitter between 16ms and 50ms per frame. For example, it'll render several frames at 16ms, slide up to 50ms over a dozen frames or so, render several more frames at 50ms, then slide back down to 16ms and repeat. I discovered that if I set the CPU governor to "performance" (or "conservative", curiously enough) instead of the default "ondemand" it'll render with full effects at full speed. Alternatively, if I leave the governor alone and insert a busy loop in my code (increment a variable 100,000 times per frame) that bumps my CPU usage up enough to transition to a higher clock rate and render smoothly as well.

So it seems on this phone my app is bottlenecked by the GPU, but only when it throttles down. Now, I wouldn't mind if the GLSurfaceView rendered at a slower rate according to the GPU clock, but my problem here is that I'm getting the bursts of alternating high and low frame rates which makes my animation look fluid/frameskippy/fluid/frameskippy/etc. several times per second. It seems like the GPU clock is ramping up and down like crazy?

I got a visible improvement by using RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY and calling requestRender() on a strictly timed thread, but the darn GPU keeps ramping up and down. Why won't it either render as fast as it can at the slower clock, or just jump to and STAY AT the higher clock?

The best solution I've come up with so far is using a sliding window to detect the average frame update time, then applying the difference from the target frame time until the two values converge. The time between render updates is slower but at least it's roughly constant. So that works in theory, but it takes several seconds to reach a steady state and it looks bad in the meantime.

I think a third option might be to cannibalize the GLSurfaceView source and make a custom version. From what I understand, the blocking GL calls are made in there, so it would be much easier for me to time render calls and react accordingly. I'm not very comfortable attempting that though because there's a lot of code in there that I'd have to spend a lot of time understanding before I could even begin to mess with it. Plus I'd then have to worry about how well version X of GLSurfaceView plays with any version Y of Android.

So, with all that said, do I have any other options here? Is there an easier fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

try fixing the frame rate by pausing the thread (thread sleep) for the remaining time to reach a constant frame rate.